# How to force logical sorting in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to sort my table in Teradata by months in a logical way so that it goes as `jan, feb, mar .......`

However when i try

`order by month_event`

I get `apr, aug ......` that is alphabetical

**I know I can associate numbers 1 to 12 for each month, then sort and then get rid of that field. Is there any other more efficient way ?**

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no other way than doing a typecast or a CASE:

```
ORDER BY month_event (DATE, FORMAT 'mmm')

ORDER BY 
  CASE month_event
    WHEN 'jan' THEN 1
    WHEN 'feb' THEN 2
    WHEN 'mar' THEN 3
    WHEN 'apr' THEN 4
    WHEN 'may' THEN 5
    WHEN 'jun' THEN 6
    WHEN 'jul' THEN 7
    WHEN 'aug' THEN 8
    WHEN 'sep' THEN 9
    WHEN 'oct' THEN 10
    WHEN 'nov' THEN 11
    WHEN 'dec' THEN 12
  END
```

The CASE should be less overhead (and it's easier to understand)

Comment: And to be a bit clearer, the first ORDER BY is if month_event is a DATE column and the second is if it is a string (CHAR or VARCHAR). Should be obvious, but just in case...

Comment: No, both are for strings. The first does a typecast on a three character month name into a date, which results in the first day of month within the current year, e.g. 'apr' -> 2013-04-01

Comment: Oh that's cool, I didn't understand that. Another late Christmas gift!